# Is there an API that can access txID info for all the top networks?

Tags: api, networking, cryptography, etherscan

I have deposits with multiple coins on multiple networks, I need to access data from each txID, I dont want to call the api of etherscan, solanascan, polygonscan, btcscan. It woulld be easier with one api having access to all transaction Info.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.